# Understanding biasing typologies of a class AB amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bias

I've been trying to understand how the biasing of a simple class AB amplifier works and I've encountered a few comprehension issues.

Here's the simplest way I found to bias it:
[image]

If we apply kirchhoff laws we end up with:

`Vin + Vd = Vbe + Vout <=> Vin = Vout` if we assume that `Vd = Vbe`

Great, we've got an unity voltage gain amplifier that can amplify our power output.

Now here comes the tricky part, I've also seen this circuit being used all over the internet (just pretend that the diodes are a Vbe multiplier if you prefer that):

[image]

If we do apply kirchhoff laws yet again, we get (assuming that Vd=Veb=Vbe):

`Vin + 2Vd = Vbe + Vout <=> Vout = Vin + Vd`

Obviously we stumble across the same outcome if we're applying it on the other path:

`Vin + Veb = Vout <=> Vout = Vin + Vd`

And yet, simulating those two circuits yields the same results. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you should look at Vout before the C2 capacitor

Comment: You've labeled Vin and Vout as the AC coupled nodes (i.e. they have zero DC bias), yet are doing a DC analysis, it looks?  That is, you've completely skipped over C1 and C2 in your loops, which of course can have any DC value, making the analysis irrelevant. If you are investigating the biasing, you must include R1 and R2 instead. The AC medium-frequency approximation (C1, C2 shorted, ignore DC) will give the correct result, but the question of how many Vbe's offset then also goes out the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright lads I found the answer, I'm posting it here in case it can help somebody in need instead of simply deleting it.

After thinking about it for a little while I remembered the golden rule of amplifier analysis:

> Always separate the DC analysis from the AC analysis

In the case of those two circuits, the DC analysis remains the same for the both of them: the "middle point" of the bridge (in-between the two diodes) as well as the emitter point both have a voltage of 12V (Vcc/2).

By applying my signal to the middle point of the bridge I do not create any DC offset differential between the input and the output and thus Vin = Vout.

But when applying it to the cathode of D2, I'm applying it to a point which has a DC offset of (Vcc/2)-Vd and my output (right before C2) still has a DC offset of Vcc/2. Thus, the Vd in Vout = Vin + Vd isn't an AC component but a DC one which therefore doesn't alter my AC signal in any way whatsoever.

I wouldn't have gotten things mixed up if I properly separated the DC analysis from the AC, my apologies.

Comment: Very good that you found a way to explain it! My recommendation is that when trying to understand circuits, look for simpler and more intuitive human-friendly explanations. In this case, just think of the charged capacitors as "rechargeable batteries" in series with the AC source, and how their voltages add/subtract from the AC voltage. Similarly, think of diodes as constant voltage sources or (better) as constant-voltage nonlinear resistors. So, like in capacitors, their voltages are added/subtracted to/from the total Vin+Vc voltage. Avoid thinking of capacitors as an AC  "short connection".

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few simulations of the input circuit that you can play around with to get an idea of what is going on there.

### Real circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPLwWU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Class AB amplifier biasing_1]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcykCZ.png)</sup>

[image: Class AB amplifier biasing_2]

### Capacitors as voltage sources

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5M0Ug.png)</sup>

[image: Class AB amplifier biasing_3]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feBgrO.png)</sup>

[image: Class AB amplifier biasing_4]

### Diodes as voltage sources

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCuGuD.png)</sup>

[image: Class AB amplifier biasing_5]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGxzcH.png)</sup>

[image: Class AB amplifier biasing_3]

### Conclusion

As you can see, the results are the same…

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this topology (although I've tried a little) but I think that you're forgetting the effect of C1 and C2. They allow the input and output to operate at different DC offsets. The voltage on the right hand side of C1 and left hand side of C2 will be different in the two circuits. The AC signal won't care whether it's injected at D1's anode or cathode or at D2's cathode.

---

From the comments:

> The voltage on the lefthand of C2 will remain the same in both circuits as the DC component remains the same.

Agreed.

> The voltage on the right hand of C1 will indeed see a difference of Vd between the two circuits but I'm failing to see how that prevents the addition of Vd to the output signal.

To \$ V_{out} \$? How could it when C2 is blocking any DC offset?

Comment: The voltage on the lefthand of C2 will remain the same in both circuits as the DC component remains the same. The voltage on the right hand of C1 will indeed see a difference of Vd between the two circuits but I'm failing to see how that prevents the addition of Vd to the output signal.

Comment: See the update.